# Delphi XE4 shutdown OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, shutdown, delphi-xe4

I'm new to using OSX API by Delphi XE4. So, I don't know how to translate XCode sample to Delphi.

Can anybody give me an example of how can I shutdown my MacOS by calling OSX API ?

Updated: I got an Apple article here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1134/_index.html

But it seems the APIs are not declared. I tried to use MacAPI units and type the functions, the compilers said not found.

Comment: Should not be On Hold.  Question is clear as edited.   It has been answered nicely in this blog post.  http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/programmatically-shutting-down-restarting-sleeping-or-logging-off-on-os-x/

Comment: My full reply is here: http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/programmatically-shutting-down-restarting-sleeping-or-logging-off-on-os-x/
I think it's not a really "native solution". Firstly, in my opinion, ActiveScript is not really popular on modern OSX version from OSX Lion. Apple removed ActiveScript icon from their application list.
Few days ago, I thought about calling OSX command line such as "/sbin/shutdown -t now" to shutdown OSX but as I said, this is not an official way to do.
I wish to translate OSX APIs declaration and use it by calling API as Apple's sample.

Comment: I think if the API can be called as following is great: 

procedure NSBeep; cdecl;
  external '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit' name '_NSBeep';